# How to explain this SQL Server CE behaviour - not updating

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sql-server-ce

I have WinForms application am building and am using SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5.

Whenever I run the WinForms application and I have a query editor open in Visual Studio afterwards, any update query I run does not reflect in the application. If I run `Select` query to view the updated records, I could see from the query result that the data has changed but does not reflect in the application.

If I close the application and run it again the updates reflects in the application.

Is this normal? What is the best explanation for this?

**UPDATE**

*from C#*

```
string sqlceConnString = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\medicstores.sdf";
```

*from new Query Connection window in Visual Studio*

```
C:\Users\user12345\...\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\StockPro\StockProFormUI\medicstores.sdf
```

**Update**

I think this may be due to the application duplicating the database file copying it to `\StockPro\StockProFormUI\bin\Debug\medicstores.sdf` instead of using `\StockPro\StockProFormUI\medicstores.sdf`.

I think `|DataDirectory|` was resolved to `\StockPro\StockProFormUI\bin\Debug\medicstores.sdf` by the application which makes it a new copy from the physical file in `\StockPro\StockProFormUI\medicstores.sdf` and thus they are not the same

Comment: Show your connection string. Almost every time, this issue is because you are connecting to two different copies of your .sdf file.

Comment: but when I close the Winform Application and re-run, the updates become visible. If the query window is opened first, the database file is locked so the Application won't run. This shows they are accessing the same file

Comment: I think this may be due to the application duplicating the database file copying it to `\StockPro\StockProFormUI\bin\Debug\medicstores.sdf` instead of using `\StockPro\StockProFormUI\medicstores.sdf`

Comment: Yeah, like I said, your connection string is telling the app to make a copy of your .sdf file. Change your connection string to point to the same, static .sdf file that Visual Studio is pointing to.

Comment: I need to remove the `|DataDirectory|` and use an full path? right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check you Connection string first.

Disconnect your SQL CE database on your server explorer.

I also had that problem before.
You need to get where is the exact location of your sqlce database and and then change your connection string.

Test it first to place you sqlce on your drive c:\ and add Persist Security Info=False; on the end. and use the exact database file path.

```
private SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=C:\\medicstores.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;");
```

You can use SQL CE Tool to view your SQLCE database instead of using visual studio.

[SQL Server CE Query Tool - Code Porject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33433/SQL-Server-CE-Query-Tool)

Regards

Comment: but when I close the Winform Application and re-run, the updates become visible.

Comment: try to disconnect your sqlce database on your server explorer..then copy your sqlce file on your drive C:\\ and add ;Persist Security Info=False; on your connection string to test.

Comment: I think this may be due to the application duplicating the database file copying it to `\StockPro\StockProFormUI\bin\Debug\medicstores.sdf` instead of using `\StockPro\StockProFormUI\medicstores.sdf`

Comment: yes thats why you need to disconnect your databse on your server explorer and try not to use exact file path not data directory.